# Polaroid Effect Acting Strange

Tags: css

I'm new to css and have been getting by fine so far from going through tutorials and reading some of the great advice on this site but I just cant get my head around this one. I am trying to achieve a Polaroid effect using css and am getting some weird effects on my website. I have tested the code on jsfiddle and it works fine, I even copied the entire sites css and it still worked fine in jsfiddle. But as soon as I use that code on my website the margins, padding, rotation etc. are wrong.

Please help I'm at a loss here and don't know what could be affecting it, my only idea is that for some reason the css selectors I am using are not selecting the elements properly.

The site page is: http://kamhairandmakeup.co.uk/vintage/

The JSFiddle is:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/deepwaterlizard/NxsUQ/1/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

or

http://jsfiddle.net/deepwaterlizard/NxsUQ/1/

I can post the css and html here if needed but didn't want to take up too much space, thank you in advance.

Comment: If you look at your generated source code compared to your jsfiddle, it's almost completely different? You have additional <p> tags in your site that don't appear in the jsfiddle (between each polaroid). Try looking at that and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I may have edited one and not updated the other in haste. I have now updated the site to reflect the jsfiddle. So the <p> tags seem to be the issue, I will have to try and find a way of removing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but for starters, the first image (black and white) has this html on your site:

```
<p>                
    <!--the caption that appears below the image-->
    <br>
</p>
```

after `figcaption` tag and its not present in your fiddle.

Looks like you are using Wordpress. Its editor will generate a lot of `<p>` tags, e.g. for each new line, it will generate `<p>&nbsp;</p>` or empty `<p></p>`

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't realize the wordpress editor did this. So would I be right in thinking that I should find the html file on the host and add the code to the file directly?

Comment: Wordpress editor allows you to edit html directly, you can erase all unused tags there. However, I think it would be better to look into http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API. This will allow you to use something simple as [polaroid images="path/to/image, path/to/image"] in editor and then it would transform into your polaroid div during content filtering that wordpress does before echoing content of your post/page

Comment: Ok I will give that a go, sounds like a good idea. Thank you for the help.